# Select All matches that clubs played with an interval less than three days between games

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

- Club - Stores all clubs (id_club, name)
- Match - Store all matches   (id_club1, id_club2, dateMatch, result)

The match has club 1 and club 2.

And I Have to select all matches that clubs played with an interval less than three days between games.

This is my code:

```
select *, DATEDIFF(day, m1.date, j2.data) from matches m1, matches m2
where DATEDIFF(day, m1.dateMatch, m2.dateMatch)<3
and m1.dateMatch<m2.dateMatch
and (m1.id_club1=m2.id_club2)
```

please execute this code:

```
create table club(id_club int identity(1,1) primary key, name varchar(50))

create table matches(id_club1 int, id_club2 int, dateMatch datetime, result int)

insert into club values ('Barcelona')
insert into club values ('Botafogo')
insert into club values ('Manchester United')
insert into club values ('Vasco')

insert into matches values (1, 2, '2014-12-04', 1)
insert into matches values (1, 3, '2014-12-08', 1)
```

but it doesn't working.

Could you help me?

Comment: Can you specify what errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updates, and compensating for the fact that your Matches table has no primary key (which, by the way, you should seriously consider changing if it's even remotely possible):

```
create table club(id_club int identity(1,1) primary key, name varchar(50))

create table matches(id_club1 int, id_club2 int, dateMatch datetime, result int)

insert into club values ('Barcelona')
insert into club values ('Botafogo')
insert into club values ('Manchester United')
insert into club values ('Vasco')

insert into matches values (1, 2, '2014-12-04', 1)
insert into matches values (1, 3, '2014-12-08', 1)
insert into matches values (1, 4, '2014-12-10', 1)


SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM 
    Matches a
     INNER JOIN 
    Matches b ON 
      (
          (
            a.id_club1 IN (b.id_club1, b.id_club2) OR 
            a.id_club2 IN (b.id_club1, b.id_club2)
          ) AND
        ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, a.DateMatch, b.DateMatch)) <= 3
      ) AND 
        NOT (a.id_club1 = b.id_club1 AND a.id_club2 = b.id_club2 AND a.dateMatch = b.dateMatch AND a.result = b.result)

DROP TABLE Club
DROP TABLE Matches
```

Comment: Sorry for delaying and thanks a lot. But I added only two registers on my matches table and your select shows 4 lines. I added a distinct before the a.* and it's working. thanks a lotttttttt

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it working, I've edited the answer to add the `DISTINCT`.  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Oh, thanks. But it was a mistake. :/ It doesn't works 100%. For example, when they cross with the same line. :/ I tried to put conditions where each value != for each value. But it doesn't works. Can you insert two rows and test it? please. Thanks a lot. Yes, I will click on check-mark. :´p

Comment: Does your matches table have a primary key or can you add one?

Comment: No, I can't do it. :/

Comment: Thanks for posting - stuff like that is best as an edit to your original post, not a comment (as you can see, comments are hard to read and things can get truncated).  Why don't you edit that SQL back into your package, and I'll work on updating my answer.

Comment: I edited my post with the create statements e insert for testing. thanks

Comment: I posted a revision, adding some extra test data in. Does this look correct?

Comment: I guess it is correct. Wait a moment, I'm testing and I am going to click the check-mark. Thanks a lot.